# add a class to every other three lines in jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
<ul id="test">
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li> // add a class to this li
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>  // add a class to this li
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li> // add a class to this li
</ul>
```

how to use jquery to add a class to the above li lines which i add a comment. thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('#test > li:nth-child(3n)').addClass('foo');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/32tKY/
API docs: http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Comment: beat me to it though my syntax is different

Comment: It should be `:nth-child(3n)`

Comment: @H3S and lo, it is, and has been.

Comment: kasdega,what's your ways to get that. i want to know, thank you.

Comment: @MattBall awesome answer, you just saved me hours of buggering around. Thankyou

Answer (score 2):

[Here is an excellent breakdown on how nth-child works at CSS Tricks.](http://css-tricks.com/5452-how-nth-child-works/)

Comment: Unfortunately CSS tricks gets it wrong, calling `:nth-child()` a "pseudo-selector" when it's [actually a pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo).

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul li:nth-child(3n)').addClass('blah');
});
```

check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7vMdx/)